# Unable to use d3.sum() multiple times in d3.flatrollup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have a JSON data which contains mulitple objects including repeating 'branch names' and remaining unique data. I want to consolidate all the branch names data adding up all the datapoints so that there is a single object per 'branch name'.

I used [`d3.flatrollup()`](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-flatgroup), and for addition I have used `d3.sum()` but it is accepting only single properties.

How can I add all the remaining fields data and assign them to a 'branch name' accordingly?

```js
var test = [
  { branch_name: "madhapur", total_visits: "75", paid: "80", }, 
  { branch_name: "madhapur", total_visits: "50", paid: "55", },
  { branch_name: "manikonda", total_visits: "15", paid: "60", },
  { branch_name: "manikonda", total_visits: "35", paid: "20", },
  { branch_name: "krishna Nagar", total_visits: "95", paid: "30", },
];

var gfg1 = d3.flatRollup(
  test,
  (v) => d3.sum(v, (d) => d.total_visits),
  (d) => d.branch_name
);
console.log(gfg1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.6.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I get this output:

```
// output:
["madhapur", 125]
["manikonda", 50]
["krishna Nagar", 95]
```

The desired output is:

```
// Desired Output:
["madhapur", 125, 135]
["manikonda", 50, 80]
["krishna Nagar", 95, 30];
```